# why postgresql got not right id?

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql:

step1:

I got the error :

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "question_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(11) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO question (content,uid,answer_count,answer_users,view_count,status,created_at,updated_at,attach) values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9) returning *
LOG:  statement: DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000001
```

step2:

I call the sentence:

```
master=# ALTER SEQUENCE question_id_seq RESTART WITH 110702;
```

step3:

insert a question, but the question_id is 11 not which i expect 110703.

my table like:

```
CREATE TABLE question (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    content text, 
    uid int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    attach text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    answer_count int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    status smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

add my serverlog:

```
LOG:  statement:
LOG:  statement: insert into "public"."question" ( "uid", "content") values ( '1', '1')
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "question_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(30) already exists.
STATEMENT:  insert into "public"."question" ( "uid", "content") values ( '1', '1')
LOG:  statement:
LOG:  statement: ALTER SEQUENCE question_id_seq RESTART WITH 110706
LOG:  statement:
LOG:  statement: insert into "public"."question" ( "uid", "content") values ( '1', '1')
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "question_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(31) already exists.
STATEMENT:  insert into "public"."question" ( "uid", "content") values ( '1', '1')
```

Comment: check `select nextval('question_id_seq');`

Comment: master=# select nextval('question_id_seq'); 
  +---------+
  | nextval |
  +---------+
  | 110703  |
  +---------+
  1 rows in set (0.02 sec)

Comment: Are you sure that `question_id_seq` is the sequence being used? What does `\d question` have to say inside `psql`? Are you sure you're doing both things in the same database?

Comment: This is my pgsql serverlog:

Comment: Please don't additional information as comments. **Edit** your question.

Comment: I agree with @mu: show us what you get with `\d question` I would be willing to bet that `id` uses another sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I am wrong, \d question shows i do not use quesiton_id_seq, but use question_id_seq1. Thanks mu